# NSFetchedResultsController not informed about model changes

Tags: ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Got somehow lost on something what worked in other projects and now stopped working.

I've got a controller (A) (subclass of NSObject) which has a NSFetchedResultsController for entities of class kClassCycleQuestionDetails.
My ManagedObjectContext is initiated with NSMainQueueConcurrencyType.

In another controller (B) I start inserting entities of the above class and start a save on every tenth object.

```
[self.moc performBlock:^{
        [self prepareNewCycle];
    }];
```

The context posts the NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification (received in B) but I never see the controllers delegate method `- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller` called in A.

Both controller share the same managed object context, so I should see model changes?!

Has anyone an idea.

Edited:
For clarification: prepareNewCycle inserts a cycle entity into the context and than
adds entities of kClassCycleQuestionDetails to the cycle entity (to-many relationship).

Here's the code for the controller A's fetchedResultsController

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

/*
 Set up the fetched results controller.
 */
// Create the fetch request for the entity
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
// Edit the entity name as appropriate.
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:kClassCycleQuestionDetails inManagedObjectContext:self.moc];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

// Set the batch size to a suitable number.
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:[self predicateForExamCycleMode:self.cycle.examQuestionModeValue cycleId:self.cycle.cycle_id]];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:kQCQDCycleQuestionDetails_id ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

// Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
// nil for section name key path means "no sections".
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                                                         initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                         managedObjectContext:self.moc
                                                         sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                         cacheName:NSStringFromClass([self class])];
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;


[NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:NSStringFromClass([self class])];
NSError *error = nil;
if (![_fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    ALog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

return _fetchedResultsController;
```

}

Comment: Did you set the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate? Is the A controller declared as implementing the protocol?

Comment: Yes, delegate is set. Controller A is also declared as <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> but as this is only for the compiler to check if you have implemented the necessary methods, it doesn't make any difference.